# Trying to understand display specs of macbook pro

Tags: display, resolution

I want to buy a monitor to connect to my macbook pro. From apple's [website](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/) this is what I have gathered:

> Retina display
> 15.4-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit display with IPS technology; 2880-by-1800 native resolution at 220 pixels per inch with support for
> millions of colors
>
> Supported scaled resolutions:
>
> 1920 by 1200
>
> 1680 by 1050
>
> 1280 by 800
>
> 1024 by 640
>
> 500 nits brightness
>
> Wide color (P3)
>
> True Tone technology

**Video Support:**

> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display
> at millions of colors and:
>
> Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880
> resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
>
> Up to four displays with
> 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
>
> Thunderbolt 3
> digital video output
>
> Native DisplayPort output over USB‑C VGA, HDMI,
> DVI, and
>
> Thunderbolt 2 output supported using adapters (sold
> separately)

Questions:

Most monitors I can find online in my preferred price range support 1920x1080 resolution. Will they work with macbook pro as I cannot find 1920x1080 in the supported resolutions above?

Referring to "Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880" - does it mean each monitor has 5120x2880 resolution? That seems awfully large and I cannot find any monitor with so much resolution.

What would be a middle-of-the-road recommended resolution to buy? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Will they work with macbook pro as I cannot find 1920x1080 in the supported resolutions above?

Yes,they would work just fine.But only with resolution of 1920*1080 or below.

2.Referring to "Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880" - does it mean each monitor has 5120x2880 resolution?

You could output 5120*2880,but the monitor may not support it.

3.What would be a middle-of-the-road recommended resolution to buy?

To use an external display from a MacBook Pro ,I would only recommend displays with a resolution of 4K or 5K.

One thing you have to know about MacBook and external display is the output is blurry due to the font used by OS X,and the only solution to this is high resolution in much smaller display, or HiDPI.

Comment: Thanks. My common sense is telling me to go with 2560x1440 resolution monitor. I am not going to use the monitor for gaming or photo editing or design.

Comment: @morpheus I have seen 2k monitors connected as external display for MacBook..still blurry.

Comment: the 4K resolution 3840 x 2160 is not among the supported resolutions on apple website. I think the monitor will still work but could someone explain me why apple does not list it as supported resolution?

Comment: this is the monitor i finally ordered https://www.amazon.com/LG-27UD58-B-27-Inch-Monitor-FreeSync/dp/B01IRQAYPE/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1541127236&sr=8-3&keywords=lg+27+4k+monitor in case it helps someone